# Evaluate $\biggl(\frac{V_{tetrahedron}}{V_{ellipsoid}}\biggr)_{max}$ for the given scenario

Tags: geometry, optimization, maxima-minima

What is the maximum ratio of the volumes of a tetrahedron $ABCD$ inscribed inside an ellipsoid of radii $a,b,c$, provided that the tetrahedron contain the center of the ellipsoid (within it, or on a face or edge thereof)?

Otherwise stated, evaluate $\biggl(\frac{V_{tetrahedron}}{V_{ellipsoid}}\biggr)_{max}\biggl|\cup{abc}\in{ABCD}$

Comment: The Cayley-Menger determinant equation for calculating the volume of any given tetrahedron $ABCD$ with sides when the height is unknown or random is:

$$\hat{D}=288V^2=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & \overline{ab}^2 & \overline{ac}^2 & \overline{ad}^2\\
1 & \overline{ab}^2 & 0 & \overline{bc}^2 & \overline{bd}^2\\
1 & \overline{ac}^2 & \overline{bc}^2 & 0 & \overline{cd}^2\\
1 & \overline{ad}^2 & \overline{bd}^2 & \overline{cd}^2 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ where $\hat{D}$ is the determinant and also $V_{tetrahedron}$.

Comment: So the ratios of the two volumes can be expressed in terms of $\overline{ab}, \overline{ac}, \overline{ad}, \overline{bc}, \overline{bd}, \overline{cd}$ (from points $A,B,C,D$) as the following expression:

Comment: $$\frac{V_{tetrahedron}}{V_{ellipsoid}}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac
{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & \overline{ab}^2 & \overline{ac}^2 & \overline{ad}^2\\
1 & \overline{ab}^2 & 0 & \overline{bc}^2 & \overline{bd}^2\\
1 & \overline{ac}^2 & \overline{bc}^2 & 0 & \overline{cd}^2\\
1 & \overline{ad}^2 & \overline{bd}^2 & \overline{cd}^2 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}}{288}}}{\frac{4}{3}abc\pi}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\hat{D}}{288}}}{\frac{4}{3}abc\pi}
$$

Comment: I haven't tried to simplify the matrix further, but at any rate this will only provide the equation to find the ratio $\frac{V_{tetrahedron}}{V_{ellipsoid}}$ for given values or in general, when I want to know the maximum ratio for the stipulation that $\cup{abc}\in{ABCD}$.